# Animating background position works on jQuery 1.4.4 but not on 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, versions

I've run into a problem.

I have a script i'm tinkering with. All runs fine but only on jQuery 1.4.4. When I move up a version, let's say the latest (1.7.2) the script will not run. What gives?!

```
var bouncespeed = 450;

function bounce(currentA) {
    newx = Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    newy = Math.floor(3 * Math.random());
    newspeed = bouncespeed + Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    $(currentA).animate({
        backgroundPosition: newx + 'px ' + newy + 'px'
    }, newspeed, 'linear', function() {
        bounce(currentA);
    });
}

$('.bubble').each(

function() {
    $(this).css({
        backgroundPosition: '5px 5px'
    });
    bounce(this);
});
```

Play time!: http://jsfiddle.net/mdecler/rgBeW/2/

Comment: So have you even tried to debug it?

Comment: if there is no bugs in the code - then it works as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a documented bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8160) affecting jQuery from version 1.5. So actually there's no way to animate that property on jQuery 1.7.2

You could instead use `.css()` instead of animate and then call the function with a small timeout, but the effect would be not really smooth

Otherwise do instead an animation over the `div` itself, changing their `margin-top/left properties`

Comment: Thx for the info @F. Calderan, but I'll stick to 1.4.4. To much hassle :P