# Jquery animate on background position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell me why this jquery isnt working?

I have a list like so:

```
      <div id="services">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#">menu item1</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#">menu item2</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#">menu item3</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#">menu item4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And I want to slide in the background image from the left on hover and reverse it on mouseout.

The following jquery code isnt doing anything on moueover or mouseout. What am I missing here?

```
$(function(){       
    $('li.menu a').css( {backgroundPosition: "-416px 0"})
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0px 0px)"}, 500)
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-416px 0)"}, 500)
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot animate backgroundPosition with newer version of jQuery: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10533780/1098851

Comment: well thats no good! Why aint they fix such a bug?

Comment: anyway I could just fade in the background and make it look like its coming from the left?

Comment: in that post I suggested some workarounds like animating the top/left properties of container (a slight markup/css change could be needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have luck:)
I run in the same issue yesterday. I see you, the same as I, need animation only on X axis.

So all you need to do is pass single parameter to backgroundPosition, which is default for X axis. Also pass int, which is default for pixels.

```
$('li.menu a').css({
     backgroundPosition: -416
}).mouseover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: 0}, 500)
}).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: -416}, 500)
});
```

Comment: No this is actually working!! Its doing exaclty what I wanted. Not usre how browser compatable it is?

Comment: just edited you code: http://jsfiddle.net/LpG2W/4/.  Also I edited my answer. It's compatible with all current browsers, and for IE8+

Comment: Thanks, One more thing how do I make the first li a tag active by default so that the back ground shows by default on this one and then will return to being default when the user is not cycling through the list items with his mouse?

Comment: Attach events on mouseover and mouseout on whole list. Then find first child in that list $(this).find(':first-child')  and change it state

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't animate background position, you can do something like this:

```
$('li.menu a').css({
    opacity: 0.5,
    marginLeft: "-5px"
});

$('li.menu a').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginLeft: "0px",
        opacity: 1
    }, 500)
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginLeft: "-5px",
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500)
});
```

**[Just a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/146/)**

Comment: still does nothing when i try it.

Comment: @user794846 does `backgroundPosition` work on `a`, as much I know It work on `background image`

Comment: @user794846 check my demo, I think you can get idea form this

Comment: You move whole item, not background. It's acceptable only in some cases. For proper solution, but only for X axis see my solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't do that without [a plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('li.menu a').css({background-position-x:"-416px",background-position-y:"0"}); 

$('li.menu a').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({background-position-x:"0",background-position-y:"0"}, 500)
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({background-position-x:"-416px",background-position-y:"0"}, 500)
});
```