# jQuery 1.7 - hover won't work

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have a code, a simple hover effect, working fine in jQuery 1.4 but not working in jQuery 1.7

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* When a thumbnail is hovered over do shine */
    $('.large_thumb').hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").css("background-position", "-167px 0");
        $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: '167px 0'
        }, 600);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: '167px 0'
        }, 600);
    });
});​
```

What it should do:

move a transparent shine-like PNG over content manipulating `bg-position` on `onmouseover`. The effect shouldn't be repeated on `onmouseout` thus the second function.

For some reason this super basic code won't work in the latest jQuery 1.7 but still works in 1.4.

I've read documentation and seem to use the right method, hover. where seems to be the problem in my code?

edit:

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3QRGD/

Comment: maybe you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533509/animating-background-position-works-on-jquery-1-4-4-but-not-on-1-7-2

Comment: so bg position cant be animated with 1.7?

Comment: Jumping from 1.4 to 1.7 has a bunch of differences. Version 1.6 broke a lot of stuff.

Comment: any idea how would i achieve the same thing in 1.7?

Comment: yes, http://jsfiddle.net/3QRGD/

Comment: You can use the jQuery Animate `step` callback, please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the jQuery Animate [`step`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) function with a "useless" CSS property (i.e. border-spacing, something you'll probably never use that doesn't affect the layout):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/tTddS/

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /* When a thumbnail is hovered over do shine */
    $('.large_thumb').hover(function() {
        var shine = $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine");

        $(shine).css("background-position", "-167px 0");
        $(shine).stop().animate({
            "border-spacing": -167
        }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(shine).css("background-position", now + "px 0px");
            },
            duration: 600
        });



    }, function() {
        var shine = $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine");

        $(shine).stop().animate({
            "border-spacing": -167
        }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(shine).css("background-position", now + "px 0px");
            },
            duration: 600
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: thx that worked allthough in the wrong direction and i couldnt fix it, for anyone interested i fixed the original code by removing the "px" and the second value which seems to cause problems here the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3QRGD/1/